# Create a CUDA/cpp makefile

Tags: makefile, cuda, cmake

I am a newbie in CUDA and want to compile my first programms on a Jetson TK1.
I have searched the Internet and also this Site but dont found something, that was helpful for me.
I have found this example 
http://bikulov.org/blog/2013/12/24/example-of-cmake-file-for-cuda-plus-cpp-code/
and tried to compile the CUDA example oceanFFT which runs with the sample Makefile.
http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/1.1-Beta/x86_website/samples.html#oceanFFT

I have changed this  CMakeLists.txt a little bit, but I dont know if I did this correct.

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)
PROJECT(lbmslv)

FIND_PACKAGE(CUDA REQUIRED)
FIND_PACKAGE(MPI REQUIRED)
FIND_PACKAGE(OpenGL REQUIRED)

INCLUDE(FindCUDA)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(/usr/local/cuda/include ${MPI_INCLUDE_PATH})
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(/usr/local/cuda-6.5/samples/common/inc ${CUS_INCLUDE_PATH})
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(/usr/local/cuda-6.5/samples/common/lib/linux/armv7l  ${GLEW_INCLUDE_PATH})

FILE(GLOB SOURCES "*.cu" "*.cpp" "*.c" "*.h")
CUDA_ADD_EXECUTABLE(lbmslv ${SOURCES})

LIST(APPEND CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++0x -O3 -ffast-math -Wall")

LIST(APPEND CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS --compiler-options -fno-strict-aliasing -lineinfo -use_fast_math -Xptxas -dlcm=cg)
LIST(APPEND CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20)
LIST(APPEND CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30)
LIST(APPEND CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(lbmslv /usr/local/cuda/lib/libcudart.so ${MPI_LIBRARIES})
```

When I run this I get a lot errors with :

```
undefined reference to ..  gl.., glew.., glut..
```

so, not linked to this Libraries.
What did I wrong?

My problem with the sample Makefiles is, that they are to complicate for my.
I have also tried to make the sample Makefile easier.

```
# Location of the CUDA Toolkit
CUDA_PATH       ?= /usr/local/cuda-6.5

OSUPPER = $(shell uname -s 2>/dev/null | tr "[:lower:]" "[:upper:]")
OSLOWER = $(shell uname -s 2>/dev/null | tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]")

OS_SIZE    = $(shell uname -m | sed -e "s/x86_64/64/" -e "s/armv7l/32/" -e "s/aarch64/64/")
OS_ARCH    = $(shell uname -m)
ARCH_FLAGS =

DARWIN = $(strip $(findstring DARWIN, $(OSUPPER)))
ifneq ($(DARWIN),)
    XCODE_GE_5 = $(shell expr `xcodebuild -version | grep -i xcode | awk '{print $$2}' | cut -d'.' -f1` \>= 5)
endif

# Take command line flags that override any of these settings

# ARCH == ARMv7
    OS_SIZE    = 32
    OS_ARCH    = armv7l
    ARCH_FLAGS = -target-cpu-arch ARM

# Common binaries
GCC := arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
NVCC := $(CUDA_PATH)/bin/nvcc -ccbin $(GCC)

# internal flags
NVCCFLAGS   := -m${OS_SIZE} ${ARCH_FLAGS}
CCFLAGS     :=
LDFLAGS     :=

# Extra user flags
EXTRA_NVCCFLAGS   ?=
EXTRA_LDFLAGS     ?=
EXTRA_CCFLAGS     ?=

# OS-specific build flags
      ifeq ($(abi),gnueabi)
        CCFLAGS += -mfloat-abi=softfp
      else
        # default to gnueabihf
        override abi := gnueabihf
        LDFLAGS += --dynamic-linker=/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3
        CCFLAGS += -mfloat-abi=hard
      endif


    ifneq ($(TARGET_FS),)
        GCCVERSIONLTEQ46 := $(shell expr `$(GCC) -dumpversion` \<= 4.6)
        ifeq ($(GCCVERSIONLTEQ46),1)
            CCFLAGS += --sysroot=$(TARGET_FS)
        endif
        LDFLAGS += --sysroot=$(TARGET_FS)
        LDFLAGS += -rpath-link=$(TARGET_FS)/lib
        LDFLAGS += -rpath-link=$(TARGET_FS)/usr/lib
        LDFLAGS += -rpath-link=$(TARGET_FS)/usr/lib/arm-linux-$(abi)
    endif


# Debug build flags
ifeq ($(dbg),1)
      NVCCFLAGS += -g -G
      TARGET := debug
else
      TARGET := release
endif

ALL_CCFLAGS :=
ALL_CCFLAGS += $(NVCCFLAGS)
ALL_CCFLAGS += $(EXTRA_NVCCFLAGS)
ALL_CCFLAGS += $(addprefix -Xcompiler ,$(CCFLAGS))
ALL_CCFLAGS += $(addprefix -Xcompiler ,$(EXTRA_CCFLAGS))

ALL_LDFLAGS :=
ALL_LDFLAGS += $(ALL_CCFLAGS)
ALL_LDFLAGS += $(addprefix -Xlinker ,$(LDFLAGS))
ALL_LDFLAGS += $(addprefix -Xlinker ,$(EXTRA_LDFLAGS))

# Common includes and paths for CUDA
INCLUDES  := -I ~/NVIDIA_CUDA-6.5_Samples/common/inc
LIBRARIES :=

################################################################################

SAMPLE_ENABLED := 1

# Makefile include to help find GL Libraries
include ./findgllib.mk

# OpenGL specific libraries
ifneq ($(DARWIN),)
 # Mac OSX specific libraries and paths to include
 LIBRARIES += -L/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Libraries
 LIBRARIES += -lGL -lGLU ../../common/lib/darwin/libGLEW.a
 ALL_LDFLAGS += -Xlinker -framework -Xlinker GLUT
else
 LIBRARIES += -L ~/NVIDIA_CUDA-6.5_Samples/common/lib/$(OSLOWER)/$(OS_ARCH) $(GLLINK)
 LIBRARIES += -lGL -lGLU -lX11 -lXi -lXmu -lglut -lGLEW
endif

# Gencode arguments
ifeq ($(OS_ARCH),armv7l)
SMS ?= 20 30 32 35 37 50 52
else
SMS ?= 11 20 30 35 37 50 52
endif

ifeq ($(SMS),)
$(info >>> WARNING - no SM architectures have been specified - waiving sample <<<)
SAMPLE_ENABLED := 0
endif

ifeq ($(GENCODE_FLAGS),)
# Generate SASS code for each SM architecture listed in $(SMS)
$(foreach sm,$(SMS),$(eval GENCODE_FLAGS += -gencode arch=compute_$(sm),code=sm_$(sm)))

# Generate PTX code from the highest SM architecture in $(SMS) to guarantee forward-compatibility
HIGHEST_SM := $(lastword $(sort $(SMS)))
ifneq ($(HIGHEST_SM),)
GENCODE_FLAGS += -gencode arch=compute_$(HIGHEST_SM),code=compute_$(HIGHEST_SM)
endif
endif

LIBRARIES += -lcufft

ifeq ($(SAMPLE_ENABLED),0)
EXEC ?= @echo "[@]"
endif

################################################################################

# Target rules
all: build

build: dat

check.deps:
ifeq ($(SAMPLE_ENABLED),0)
    @echo "Sample will be waived due to the above missing dependencies"
else
    @echo "Sample is ready - all dependencies have been met"
endif

dat.o:oceanFFT.cpp
    $(EXEC) $(NVCC) $(INCLUDES) $(ALL_CCFLAGS) $(GENCODE_FLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

dat_kernel.o:oceanFFT_kernel.cu
    $(EXEC) $(NVCC) $(INCLUDES) $(ALL_CCFLAGS) $(GENCODE_FLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

dat: dat.o dat_kernel.o
    $(EXEC) $(NVCC) $(ALL_LDFLAGS) $(GENCODE_FLAGS) -o $@ $+ $(LIBRARIES)
    $(EXEC) mkdir -p ../bin
    $(EXEC) cp $@ ../bin

run: build
    $(EXEC) ./dat

clean:
    rm -f dat dat.o dat_kernel.o
    rm -rf ../bin/dat

clobber: clean
```

Is their anything else, I can make easier or shorter?

I have less experience in creating makefiles and looking for a general way to create some for CUDA. I hope you can help me.

---

EDIT:

The new cmake file is:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)
PROJECT(lbmslv)

FIND_PACKAGE(CUDA REQUIRED)
FIND_PACKAGE(MPI REQUIRED)
FIND_PACKAGE(OpenGL REQUIRED)

INCLUDE(FindCUDA)

# include every include directory
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${MPI_INCLUDE_PATH} ${GLEW_INCLUDE_PATH})
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(/usr/local/cuda-6.5/samples/common/inc ${SAMPLE_INCLUDE_PATH})

FILE(GLOB SOURCES "*.cu" "*.cpp" "*.c" "*.h")

LIST(APPEND CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++0x -O3 -ffast-math -Wall")

LIST(APPEND CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS --compiler-options -fno-strict-aliasing -lineinfo -use_fast_math -Xptxas -dlcm=cg)
LIST(APPEND CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20)
LIST(APPEND CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30)
LIST(APPEND CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35)

CUDA_ADD_EXECUTABLE(lbmslv ${SOURCES})
# add every dependency to lbmslv
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(lbmslv ${CUDA_LIBRARIES} ${MPI_LIBRARIES} ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES} ${SAMPLE_LIBRARIES})
```

I get the following terminal outputs:

```
ubuntu@tegra-ubuntu:~/Documents/CUDA/bin$ cmake ../myOzean/
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.4
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.4
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Found CUDA: /usr/local/cuda-6.5 (found version "6.5") 
-- Found MPI_C: /usr/lib/libmpi.so;/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl.so;/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libhwloc.so  
-- Found MPI_CXX: /usr/lib/libmpi_cxx.so;/usr/lib/libmpi.so;/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl.so;/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libhwloc.so  
-- Looking for XOpenDisplay in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libX11.so;/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libXext.so
-- Looking for XOpenDisplay in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libX11.so;/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libXext.so - found
-- Looking for gethostbyname
-- Looking for gethostbyname - found
-- Looking for connect
-- Looking for connect - found
-- Looking for remove
-- Looking for remove - found
-- Looking for shmat
-- Looking for shmat - found
-- Looking for IceConnectionNumber in ICE
-- Looking for IceConnectionNumber in ICE - found
-- Found X11: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libX11.so
-- Found OpenGL: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libGL.so  
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/ubuntu/Documents/CUDA/bin
ubuntu@tegra-ubuntu:~/Documents/CUDA/bin$ make
[ 50%] Building NVCC (Device) object CMakeFiles/lbmslv.dir//./lbmslv_generated_oceanFFT_kernel.cu.o
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/include/stddef.h(432): error: identifier "nullptr" is undefined

/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/include/stddef.h(432): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/c++/4.8/bits/c++config.h(190): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/exception(63): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/exception(68): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/exception(76): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/exception(83): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/exception(93): error: expected a "{"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/exception_ptr.h(64): error: function "std::current_exception" returns incomplete type "std::__exception_ptr::exception_ptr"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/exception_ptr.h(64): error: expected a "{"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/exception_ptr.h(79): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/exception_ptr.h(81): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/exception_ptr.h(82): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/exception_ptr.h(84): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/exception_ptr.h(86): error: declaration is incompatible with previous "std::current_exception"
(64): here

/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/exception_ptr.h(86): error: use of a local type to declare a function

/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/exception_ptr.h(86): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/exception_ptr.h(87): error: use of a local type to declare a function

/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/exception_ptr.h(90): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/exception_ptr.h(92): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/exception_ptr.h(95): error: incomplete type is not allowed

/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/exception_ptr.h(95): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/exception_ptr.h(116): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/exception_ptr.h(126): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/exception_ptr.h(143): error: use of a local type to declare a function

/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/exception_ptr.h(144): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/exception_ptr.h(147): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/exception_ptr.h(152): error: use of a local type to declare a function

/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/exception_ptr.h(153): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/exception_ptr.h(156): error: use of a local type to declare a function

/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/exception_ptr.h(157): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/exception_ptr.h(160): error: use of a local type to declare a function

/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/exception_ptr.h(161): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/exception_ptr.h(169): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/nested_exception.h(57): error: incomplete type is not allowed

/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/nested_exception.h(60): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/nested_exception.h(66): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/nested_exception.h(70): error: identifier "rethrow_exception" is undefined

/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/nested_exception.h(73): error: function "std::nested_exception::nested_ptr" returns incomplete type "std::__exception_ptr::exception_ptr"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/new(95): error: expected a "{"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/new(110): error: identifier "__p" is undefined

/usr/include/c++/4.8/new(111): error: expected a "{"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/new(115): error: expected a "{"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/new(116): error: expected a "{"

/usr/local/cuda-6.5/include/common_functions.h(92): warning: exception specification is incompatible with that of previous function "operator new[](std::size_t, void *)"
/usr/include/c++/4.8/new(111): here

/usr/local/cuda-6.5/include/common_functions.h(93): warning: exception specification is incompatible with that of previous function "operator delete(void *, void *)"
/usr/include/c++/4.8/new(115): here

/usr/local/cuda-6.5/include/common_functions.h(94): warning: exception specification is incompatible with that of previous function "operator delete[](void *, void *)"
/usr/include/c++/4.8/new(116): here

/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/cpp_type_traits.h(184): error: identifier "char16_t" is undefined

/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/cpp_type_traits.h(191): error: identifier "char32_t" is undefined

/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/cpp_type_traits.h(191): error: class "std::__is_integer<<error-type>>" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/cpp_type_traits.h(314): error: namespace "std::__gnu_cxx" has no member "__normal_iterator"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/cpp_type_traits.h(314): error: expected a ">"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(80): error: inline specifier allowed on function declarations only

/usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(80): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(105): error: inline specifier allowed on function declarations only

/usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(105): error: variable "std::constexpr" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(105): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(124): error: inline specifier allowed on function declarations only

/usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(124): error: variable "std::constexpr" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(124): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(143): error: inline specifier allowed on function declarations only

/usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(143): error: variable "std::constexpr" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(143): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(162): error: inline specifier allowed on function declarations only

/usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(162): error: variable "std::constexpr" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(162): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(183): error: inline specifier allowed on function declarations only

/usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(183): error: variable "std::constexpr" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(183): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(202): error: inline specifier allowed on function declarations only

/usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(202): error: variable "std::constexpr" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(202): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(221): error: inline specifier allowed on function declarations only

/usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(221): error: variable "std::constexpr" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(221): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(240): error: inline specifier allowed on function declarations only

/usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(240): error: variable "std::constexpr" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(240): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(259): error: inline specifier allowed on function declarations only

/usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(259): error: variable "std::constexpr" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(259): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(278): error: inline specifier allowed on function declarations only

/usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(278): error: variable "std::constexpr" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(278): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(297): error: inline specifier allowed on function declarations only

/usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(297): error: variable "std::constexpr" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(297): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(328): error: "constexpr" is not a function or static data member

/usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(337): error: inline specifier allowed on function declarations only

/usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(337): error: variable "std::constexpr" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(337): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(356): error: inline specifier allowed on function declarations only

/usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(356): error: variable "std::constexpr" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(356): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(375): error: inline specifier allowed on function declarations only

/usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(375): error: variable "std::constexpr" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(375): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(406): error: inline specifier allowed on function declarations only

/usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(406): error: variable "std::constexpr" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(406): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(443): error: inline specifier allowed on function declarations only

/usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(443): error: variable "std::constexpr" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath(443): error: expected a ";"

Error limit reached.
100 errors detected in the compilation of "/tmp/tmpxft_00004dfc_00000000-12_oceanFFT_kernel.compute_35.cpp1.ii".
Compilation terminated.
CMake Error at lbmslv_generated_oceanFFT_kernel.cu.o.cmake:264 (message):
  Error generating file
  /home/ubuntu/Documents/CUDA/bin/CMakeFiles/lbmslv.dir//./lbmslv_generated_oceanFFT_kernel.cu.o


make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/lbmslv.dir/./lbmslv_generated_oceanFFT_kernel.cu.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/lbmslv.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
ubuntu@tegra-ubuntu:~/Documents/CUDA/bin$
```

Comment: You need to link with OpenGL libraries like you do with OpenMPI ones: `target_include_libraries(lbmslv ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES})`.

Comment: Also you should replace `/usr/local/cuda/lib/libcudart.so` with what is returned by the `FindCUDA` module for the location of that library.

Answer (score 1):

I've changed your `CMakeLists.txt` a little bit:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)
PROJECT(lbmslv)

FIND_PACKAGE(CUDA REQUIRED)
FIND_PACKAGE(MPI REQUIRED)
FIND_PACKAGE(OpenGL REQUIRED)

INCLUDE(FindCUDA)

# include every include directory
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${MPI_INCLUDE_PATH} ${MPI_INCLUDE_PATH} ${GLEW_INCLUDE_PATH})

FILE(GLOB SOURCES "*.cu" "*.cpp" "*.c" "*.h")

LIST(APPEND CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++0x -O3 -ffast-math -Wall")

LIST(APPEND CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS --compiler-options -fno-strict-aliasing -lineinfo -use_fast_math -Xptxas -dlcm=cg)
LIST(APPEND CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20)
LIST(APPEND CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30)
LIST(APPEND CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35)

CUDA_ADD_EXECUTABLE(lbmslv ${SOURCES})
# add every dependency to lbmslv
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(lbmslv ${CUDA_LIBRARIES} ${MPI_LIBRARIES} ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!

Is this "CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS" the path to the sample directories?
Why is "MPI_INCLUDE_PATH" twice in the INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES?

Comment: @wsm: This is a typo :D. It is sufficient to write it one ;)